# Apache Ivy circular dependency

Tags: java, apache, ivy

I am new to this project. I want to build it and I am facing this issue:

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.google.gwt#gwt-elemental;2.8.0: several  problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.gwt#gwt-elemental;2.8.0 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.web.bindery#requestfactory;2.8.0 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.web.bindery#requestfactory;2.8.0 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]   com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I have read a bit about ivy, but I am not very keen with it. How do i repair these kinds of errors?

Answer (score 0):

These are unresolved dependencies meaning the libraries are not found in your organization's artifactory/repository.

You need to check in which repositories the libraries exist and then ensure those repositories are provisioned in ivy configuration.